# How to check if the file name in the #line directive matches the actual name of the file?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

Is it possible to check in compile time that the file name in the `#line` directive matches the actual name of the file being translated?

Comment: Check against what?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the meaning of #line in C language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2216540/whats-the-meaning-of-line-in-c-language)

Comment: It seems to me to be a duplicate because I have the impression that your question is based on a misunderstanding of its meaning/mechanism/behaviour.

Comment: One of the possible misunderstanding being that you might confuse it with https://www.cprogramming.com/reference/preprocessor/__FILE__.html

Comment: Or with things you see after using `-E` commandline switch. http://tigcc.ticalc.org/doc/comopts.html#SEC4

Comment: Succinctly, no — it is not possible to verify at compile time that the file name in the `#line` directive matches the actual file name.  Indeed, it is often used to ensure that a different name is presented in any diagnostics when the C code is generated from some other source language.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, Then in https://stackoverflow.com/a/30764776/9881330 when Keith Thompson is telling that it `is left as an exercise` it should be interpreted as a joke?

Comment: @pmor — yes, I think it is best interpreted as a joke.  You could consider leaving a comment asking about it, but I'm not sure whether you would get an answer.